# Total placement number of battleship game

Tags: combinatorics, packing-problem

The board is 4x4 and there are three types of battleships: 3x1, 2x1, 1x1. **One for each type**. How many total placements are possible? Notice, the ships cannot overlap **and we must use all ships**.

(there is one previous thread about this topic but seems no one actually got the right answer).

Here is my approach:

1. Calculate the total number (sample space) which is 11 (1 * 3 ship) * 24 (1 * 2 ship) * 16 (1 x 1 ship)
2. Subtract the overlap
   -> which is quite challenging to do since the discussing all cases using inclusion-exclusion principle is very time consuming and although I do believe one can get the correct solution, it is more suitable to use computer simulation.

How can we do it by hand?

Comment: by hand, I suppose you mean to calculate the no. of ways by hand, and not draw each placement and count them? Also, can some cells remain empty?

Comment: I think there are 16 placements for the ship of length 3, 8 of them have the ship on an edge, and 8 not on an edge, you should be able to count the possible placements for the ship of length 2 by considering only these two cases.

Comment: Are you only placing one of each ship on the board?

Comment: I think it may help to consider to consider ships are located by one point plus one direction (left or down). Then, writing the condition for two ships to not overlap is not very hard.

Comment: @DS Yes. What I mean is calculate the no. by hands. Since there are only three ships, some cells can remain empty.

Comment: @A.J. Clarification: We need to use all ships.

Comment: @WW1 Yes exactly. This is also my approach. For the 3x1 on the edge. There are 5 ways for the 2x1 to overlap with it (2 complete overlap + 3 overlap one cell). For the 3x1 ship not on edge, there are 8 ways to overlap.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you place as many ships of size $1 \times 1$ as you want, or only one?

Comment: @DS Sorry for the confusion. Just updated the question. So we only have three ships and one for each type. And you must use all three ships.

Answer (score 5):

I assume overlap is the actual overlap and ships are allowed to touch. If so, here is a suggested count.

There are 16 positions for 1 * 3 ship, 24 for 1 * 2, and 16 for 1 * 1.

Note that after placing 1 * 3 and 1 * 2 ships, the number of ways to place 1 * 1 is 16-5=11.

Among 16 positions of 1 * 3, exactly 8 are sharing a corner with the boundary of $4\times4$ board and 8 do not.

Each of those 8 positions for 1 * 3 that share the corner is blocking exactly 6 positions for 1 * 2. So if 1 * 3 ship is in the corner, we have 24-6=18 possible valid position for 1 * 2.

Each of those 8 positions for 1 * 3 that do not share the corner is blocking exactly 9 positions for 1 * 2. So if 1 * 3 ship is not in the corner, we have 24-9=15 possible position for 1 * 2.

Since every valid choice for 1 * 3 and 1 * 2 can be finished with 11 valid choices for 1 * 1, the answer is (assuming no arithmetic mistake is made)
$$(8 \cdot 18+8 \cdot 15) \cdot 11.$$

Similar symmetry could be used if the ships are not allowed to share an edge of a grid, or even if they are not allowed to touch by the corner.

Comment: This count correctly yields $2904$.

Comment: That's really helpful! Thanks!!!!!!!!!